# Adjusting Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a function that I take in basic format and change it to a regex.
If I pass in `###` , it turns the into the regex of `\d\d\d`

I need to adjust it know to allow for alphacharacters.

If I pass in `##?##` it should only allow `44D55`. And if I pass in real letters, it has to be those letters

So I can pass in the function `##?AA##`, so it has to be 2 numbers, 1 alphanumeric, then the letter AA and then 2 numbers.

How can adjust this function?

```
function createValidationRegEx(format){
  format = format
    .replace(/[^#\-]/g, '') //remove other chars
     .replace(/#/g, '\\d')   //convert # to \d
    .replace(/\-/g, '\\-'); //convert - to \-
  return new RegExp('^' + format + '$', 'g');
}
```

Comment: 1. `.replace(/[^#?-]/g, '') //remove other chars` and 2. `.replace(/\?/g, '[a-zA-Z]')   //convert ? to alpha`

Comment: What if I have letters in the middle that have to stay the same?
like ###BB###?? or the function should  only work with BB, but if i need the function to work with ##AA##, if has to be AA in the midle?

Comment: Difficult to understand from comments, better you edit your question and clarify all requirements at one place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow `?` in first `replace` and then replace all `?` with `[a-zA-Z]` to let it match alpha characters.

```js
function createValidationRegEx(format){
  format = format
    .replace(/[^#?-]/g, '') //remove other chars
    .replace(/#/g, '\\d')   //convert # to \d
    .replace(/\-/g, '\\-') //convert - to \-
    .replace(/\?/g, '[a-zA-Z]')   //convert ? to alpha
  return new RegExp('^' + format + '$');
}

let re = createValidationRegEx('##?##');
console.log( re );
//=> /^\d\d[a-zA-Z]\d\d$/

console.log( re.test('44D55') );
//=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want:

- `#` to be `\d`
- `?` to be `A-Z`
- `-` to stay `-`
- A letter to stay that letter.

You'll have to remove everything that is not in the list: `.replace(/[^#?A-Z-]/g, '')`.

Then replace `?` with `[A-Z]`: `.replace(/\?/g, '[A-Z]')` **BUT** keep in mind that you have to escape the carret first, or the freshly created char class will be doomed (`[A\-Z]` is not a great idea when you want to match from A to Z)

Then you're done:

```js
function createValidationRegEx(format){
  format = format
    .replace(/[^#?A-Z-]/g, '') //remove other chars
    .replace(/#/g, '\\d')      //convert # to \d
    .replace(/-/g, '\\-')      //escape - to \-
    .replace(/\?/g, '[A-Z]')   //convert ? to any letter
    ;
  return new RegExp('^' + format + '$', 'g');
}

let re = createValidationRegEx('##?AA##');
console.log( re );
re = createValidationRegEx('##?BB##');
console.log( re );
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, according to the question and comments you want to replace `#` with `\d` and `?` to match alphacharacters, possibly `[a-zA-Z]` and if you pass letters then they have to stay.

Maybe you could only replace the `#` with `\d` and the `?` with `[a-zA-Z]`:

```
function createValidationRegEx(format) {
  format = format
    .replace(/#/g, '\\d')
    .replace(/\?/g, '[a-zA-Z]');
  return new RegExp('^' + format + '$');
}
```

```js
let items = [
  ["##?##", "44D55"],
  ["##?AA##", "44DAA55"],
  ["###BB###??", "111BB111AA"],
  ["##", "12"],
  ["?", "Z"],
  ["", "Test"],
  ["###BB###??", "111AA111AA"],
  ["##?AA##", "449AA55"],
  ["?", "&"]
];

function createValidationRegEx(format) {
  format = format
    .replace(/#/g, '\\d')
    .replace(/\?/g, '[a-zA-Z]');
  return new RegExp('^' + format + '$');
}

items.forEach((item) => {
  let r = createValidationRegEx(item[0]);
  console.log(r);
  console.log("match " + item[1] + " ==> " + r.test(item[1]));
  console.log('--------------------------');
});
```